# Location property of picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, location, picturebox

I have a code to display multiple images in a Panel

```
    public List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    public List<PictureBox> pictures = new List<PictureBox>();
    public int top=10;
    public int ItemCount = 0;
    private void tsbOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.Filter="Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FileName));

            pictures.Add(new PictureBox());
            pictures[ItemCount].Image = images[ItemCount];
            pictures[ItemCount].Width = images[ItemCount].Width;
            pictures[ItemCount].Height = images[ItemCount].Height;
            pnlMain.Controls.Add(pictures[ItemCount]);
            pnlMain.Controls[ItemCount].Location=new Point(0,top);


            top += (images[ItemCount].Size.Height+10);
            ItemCount++;
        }
    }
```

But when I select the third images, the distance between the second and third images is different than that between the first and second. How can I make the distance between images equal?

Comment: How do you want to layout the PBs? All in one row or in multiple rows?

Comment: Checking again, I think your code works just fine! What do you mean by ' distance .. becomes unsually.'?? Does this change with the Images you pick?

Comment: Just one little thin you might want to improve: If you PBs have a border you should set their clientsize, not the outer bounds: `pictures[ItemCount].ClientSize = images[ItemCount].Size;` - Well and of xourse there is a FlowLayoutPanel, which will do all the layout work!

Comment: I want to layput the PBs in multiple rows and one column. The problem is the location of the third PBs is very far from the second picturebox.

Comment: So it is reproducible? Are you always picking the same images in the same order? Try to add this: `pictures[ItemCount].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;` to see the effect better!

Comment: I finally could reproduce the shift. I'm almost certain the problem is related to scrolling. See my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
int space = 10; 

if (ItemCount > 0) pnlMain.Controls[ItemCount].Location =
    new Point(0, pnlMain.Controls[ItemCount - 1].Bottom + space);
else pnlMain.Controls[ItemCount].Location = new Point(0, space );
```

Generally you need to know

- what is the `SizeMode` of the `PictureBoxes`?
- do they have a `BorderStyle` other than `None`?

But here the bug in your code is subtler: The `Location` must be set in relation to where the `PictureBox` above is located. The code with the variable `top` works, but only as long as the `Panel` isn't **scrolled**. Directly linking it to the last picture placed, will work even when you have scrolled down, I hope..

The code above places the next box in relation to the `Bottom` of the previous one with a spacing of 10 pixels.